# How to increase speed for rapidjson?

Tags: c++, json, performance, rapidjson

For below code on CentOS Linux when parsing [citm_catalog.json](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/benchmarks.html#json.benchmarks.parse_citm_catalog_json) with whitespace removed I get 354MB/sec.  How to improve performance?

[Boost benchmark][1] has rapidjson at 2469 MB/sec. With whitespace, below code runs at 846 MB/sec.

```
$cat citm_catalog.json | tr -d "[:space:]" > citm_catalog-compact.json
$ ./json_perf citm_catalog-compact.json 
Parse time for fileSz=499641 is 1.83207 ms
354 MB/sec
```

Code:

```
#if defined(__SSE4_2__)
#  define RAPIDJSON_SSE42
#elif defined(__SSE2__)
#  define RAPIDJSON_SSE2
#elif defined(__ARM_NEON)
#  define RAPIDJSON_NEON
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include "rapidjson/rapidjson.h"
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/error/en.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace rapidjson;

void errorExit(string msg, int errorCode=1)
{
    cout << msg << " errorCode=" << errorCode << endl;
    exit(errorCode);
}

//From rapidjson example
template <typename Allocator>
static char* readFile(const char* fileName, Allocator& allocator, size_t& length)
{
    FILE *fp = 0;
    fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    if (!fp)
        errorExit((string("Could not open ") + fileName));
    
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = static_cast<size_t>(ftell(fp));
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* json = reinterpret_cast<char*>(allocator.Malloc(length + 1));
    size_t readLength = fread(json, 1, length, fp);
    json[readLength] = '\0';
    fclose(fp);
    if(! json)
        errorExit(string("Could not read ") + fileName);
    
    return json;
}

void RapidJSON_test(char* fileName)
{
    int chunkSize = 64*1024;
    MemoryPoolAllocator<> jsonAllocator(chunkSize);

    size_t fileSz;
    char* json = readFile(fileName, jsonAllocator, fileSz);

    auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    Document d;
    ParseResult ok = d.ParseInsitu(json);
    if (!ok)
        errorExit("JSON parse error " +  string(GetParseError_En(ok.Code())) + " line=" + to_string(ok.Offset()));

    auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double elapsed_time_ms = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end-t_start).count();
    double elapsed_time_sec = elapsed_time_ms / 1000;
    double MB_sec = static_cast<double>(fileSz) / 1000000 / elapsed_time_sec;

    cout << "Parse time for fileSz=" << fileSz << " is " << elapsed_time_ms << " ms" << endl;
    cout << (int) MB_sec << " MB/sec" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if ((argc != 2))
        errorExit("usage: " + string(argv[0]) + " file_to_parse.json");

    char* fileName = argv[1];
    RapidJSON_test(fileName);
}
```

```
g++ -std=c++11 -m64 -O3 json_perf.cpp -I ../rapidjson/include -o json_perf
```

I tried from a simple parse to all the extra rapidjson items in the sample code.

```
  [1]: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/benchmarks.html
```

Comment: Is `-o3` a typo for `-O3`?

Comment: Good catch!  Thanks. But still slower than expected.

Comment: You expect 500 and get 497 and you complain for less than 1%?

Comment: I expect 500 with spaces/cr removed from citm_catalog.json.  Without spaces it runs at 272 MB/s

Comment: Another way of looking at it, instead of file size, is that it parsed the same number of elements in ~half the time.

Comment: By the way, did you tried SimdJson?

Comment: If you care about speed, why are you copying the file with `fread` instead of doing a zero-copy `mmap`? And when you profile the code, where do you see the time going?